# v4l-utils Based IR remote control

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, remote, uv4l, v4l2

After spending a lot of time searching how [LIRC](https://www.lirc.org/git.html) works on the raspberry pi.

Found that [LIRC](https://www.lirc.org/git.html) is deprecated & will be replaced by the [v4l-utils](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.5/media/v4l-drivers/v4l-with-ir.html).

I would like to know,

Is there any library(git hub repo) or sample example that supports the [LIRC](https://www.lirc.org/git.html) based IR Remote control application?

Comment: which application are you asking about?

Comment: @jsotola: Any Application or library that will help me to Implement custom remote configuration & IR transmission functionality.

Comment: try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/